# Convert VARCHAR in French/France Date format to Date

Tags: sql, function, date, format, ssms

I'm having some issues with date conversions and have tried a lot of the previous posts.  However, most of the previous posts seem to tackle converting English Dates to other Cultures and vice versa.

Here's the problem:

I have a date in 'String' format that get's passed into a variable.  I want to cast that into a date WITHOUT changing the language.  I want to do this so that I can look through records between dates.

```
DECLARE @style INT
DECLARE @recordDate DATE
DECLARE @srchDateBegin NVARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @localeID NVARCHAR(10)
SET @localeID = '1036'
SET @srchDateBegin = '13/04/2022'
SELECT @style = CASE WHEN @localeID = '1036' THEN 103 ELSE 101  END
```

This is all the declaration stuff (the structure is a bit different but I've written it out this way to make it a bit simpler.  Below is one way I've tried converting everything but that didn't work:

```
-SQL SELECT STUFF-
AND (@srchDateBegin = ''
    OR @recordDate BETWEEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(@srchDateBegin AS DATE), @style) AND ...
```

I then tried to use the FORMAT function in SQL but it doesn't want NVARCHARs but because I can not cast an NVARCHAR format of '16/02/1996' into a DATE, I'm stuck

```
AND (@srchDateBegin = ''
OR @recordDate BETWEEN
   CASE WHEN @style = '103' AND '@srchDateBegin' <> '' THEN FORMAT(@srchDateBegin, 'dd/MM/yyyy') ELSE '@srchDateBegin' END AND ...
```

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Did you get an error? Unexpected results? Undesired behaviour? Something else...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
DECLARE @srchDateBegin NVARCHAR(30)
SET @srchDateBegin = '13/04/2022'

SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @srchDateBegin, 105)
```

Comment: How is '13/04/2022' a French date...? Try that for '25-fév-2024'.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've written, you're actually converting something into `NVARCHAR` and not the other way around.

**Syntax** for `CONVERT` and `CAST`:

```
-- CONVERT syntax:
CONVERT(data_type(length), expression, style)

-- CAST syntax:
CAST(expression AS data_type(length))
```

Note: Only `data_type` and `expression` are required; `length` and `style` are optional.

**Suggestion:**

```
-- your code:
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(@srchDateBegin AS DATE), @style)

-- suggestion:
CONVERT(date, @srchDateBegin, @style)
```

**Sources:**

- [Quick info](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp) from W3Schools.
- [Comparing `CAST` and `CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) from Microsoft's documentation.